# Mongoid Index Creation in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I recently realized that my Indexes which I set up in my models weren't created in production automatically. I know that I can use a rake task for that:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes RAILS_ENV=production
```

But I have now a lot of Data in my DB and expect that the index creation takes some time in which the MongoDB is locked for other requests.

Does anybody know if its locked or running as background process until completion?

Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can build the index in the background so it won't affect your queries like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { field: 1}, {background: true} )
```

for more details see [**index build operations**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/)

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. the index creation lasted only for few seconds. All fear was exaggerated^^